# How can I have RabbitMQ run just once on first message send?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I'm really new to Rabbit and I am not sure how to search for the exact terms related to this question or what is the best way to execute this
I have a task that gets called when a user reaches a page. I just want that page to get run one time for that day. If more people reach that page, then the task is not executed since it already did. If no one ever goes to that page, then the task is never run.

Can someone please kindly point me to a direction as to what I should be looking for?

Comment: RabbitMQ itself cannot help you as you can't manage messages in queue after publishing. You need to store somewhere flag, was the message with same task published in the queue during current day and publish message into queue only if they wasn't. Maybe celery has some options for it, I don't know. If you need run only few tasks per day, use of  RabbitMQ can be overkill. I don't know  your specific task, but maybe easier to implement in without any queue broker, just using database?

Comment: @RidgeA okay thanks. Was hoping there are some shortcuts people use. Yea, originally I had it without any queue but it was running extremely slow. Hence I moved it to rabbit. Thanks!

Comment: maybe you was running long-term task during request processing? My suggestion was to run task after sending response to client, with cron, for example. Also you can consider Redis pub/sub as more light-weight solutions for delivering messages to consumer (be aware - in Redis if you publish message whithout subscriber it will be lost).

Answer (score 0):

You can store a key in Redis (or any other db) and set it's value with timestamp of the last running task: in each page view you will check that value and compare it to the current timestamp; if it refer to the same day, ignore. If it older than current day, update the value and trigger your task.
If your task consume too much time you can wrap it with a simple small webserver (flash/bottle/..) and your original trigger only http request..

Comment: @JamAndJammies what did you do?